# Move the scroll at middle of page at control position

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

In my aspx page I have a control at  seomwhere the middle of page. There is a lot of vertical scrollbar in the page and I am presently at the top of the page. Is there any way to move the vertical scroll position at the  control whichis at the middle of the page on button click in javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your tags, it looks like you're using the jQuery library. You can accomplish this with jQuery's [scrollTop](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/k4LCZ/

Or if you want to scroll the window itself, use [window.scrollTo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.scrollTo?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=window.scrollTo)

```
window.scrollTo(0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
var myControl = document.getElementById("controlName"); 
myControl.focus();
```

Edit: added getting a reference to the actual control

Answer (score 0):

If the content to be added is in a division(div), the best way is to go for a CSS overflow option.

```
overflow: scroll;
```

Check this link for more detailed information: [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/the-css-overflow-property/)

Answer (score 0):

Hey You can use the ID of that control to scroll down to that particular section.

Somthing like this

```
 window.onload=(function(){ document.location="#controlID";});
```

Answer (score 0):

Scroll to your position with a nice animate of the page. So when you click on your button call a function with this code:

```
var WhereToMove = jQuery("#ControlIdToMoveOn");
// using the 'html,body' will move the full page, to move a div use his id
jQuery('html,body').animate({scrollTop: WhereToMove.position().top - 10}, 1000);
```

And an example scrolling the div and not the full page: http://jsfiddle.net/k4LCZ/3/

Answer (score 0):

You can also use it with offset.

```
jQuery('html,body').animate({scrollTop: jQuery("ID_OF_THE_DIV").offset().top},'slow');
```

eg; for this scenario:

```
<a href="#ControlID" id="atagid"> <img height="39" border="0" width="37" src="/close.png"/> </a> 
jQuery('html,body').animate({scrollTop:jQuery("#atagid").offset().top},'slow');
```

OR

```
 var id = jQuery('a[href$="#ControlID"]');       
 jQuery('html,body').animate({scrollTop:jQuery(id).offset().top},'slow');
```

Hope this will help to other users....

Comment: Hi SMC will you be able to add id to a tag than you can do this on this way
<a href="#ControlID" id="atagid"> <img height="39" border="0" width="37" src="/close.png"/> </a> 
jQuery('html,body').animate({scrollTop:jQuery("#atagid").offset().top},'slow');

Comment: You can also add via this way

var id = jQuery('a[href$="#ControlID"]');

jQuery('html,body').animate({scrollTop:jQuery(id).offset().top},'slow');

if you still have problem then feel free to ask

Comment: Sorry SMC I did not get you... You mean to say I have to add above comments as an my answer?

Comment: @SMC why this answer? What has this answer to do with your solution? If you have found a solution you can post it as your own answer.